# Memory error with CKAN spatial-query plugin

Tags: ckan

I am trying to deploy CKAN portal with spatial-query plugin but when I go to the main page it gives me an internal error due to spatial-query plugin. If I remove the plugin it works correctly.

This is the error from apache log:

```
[Wed Feb 20 12:48:45.364805 2019] [:error] [pid 21928] 2019-02-20 12:48:45,364 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.161 seconds
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.588280 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] 2019-02-20 12:59:10,588 DEBUG [ckanext.harvest.model] Harvest tables defined in memory
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.595529 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] 2019-02-20 12:59:10,595 DEBUG [ckanext.harvest.model] Harvest tables already exist
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.626140 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] 2019-02-20 12:59:10,626 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.plugin] Setting up the spatial model
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.645037 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] 2019-02-20 12:59:10,644 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables defined in memory
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.648360 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] 2019-02-20 12:59:10,648 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables already exist
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.980749 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] Error - <type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>:
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985916 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] URL: http://costasol-catalog.ckan.test/
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985932 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 171 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985934 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985936 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985938 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985940 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985942 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985944 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/publisher.py', line 234 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985946 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return request.get_response(self.app)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985947 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985949 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   application, catch_exc_info=False)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985951 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985953 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985955 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985957 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985958 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985960 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985962 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/injector.py', line 54 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985964 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   response = request.get_response(self.app)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985966 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985968 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   application, catch_exc_info=False)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985969 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985971 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985973 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/pylons_app.py', line 268 in inner
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985975 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   result = application(environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985977 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985981 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985983 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 156 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985985 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985987 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/routes/middleware.py', line 131 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985989 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   response = self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985991 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/common_middleware.py', line 80 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985992 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985994 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 125 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985996 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.985998 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 324 in dispatch
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986000 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return controller(environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986002 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 212 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986003 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   res = WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986005 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 221 in __call__
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986007 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   response = self._dispatch_call()
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986009 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 172 in _dispatch_call
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986011 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   response = self._inspect_call(func)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986013 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 107 in _inspect_call
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986014 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   result = self._perform_call(func, args)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986016 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 60 in _perform_call
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986018 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   return func(**args)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986020 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/controllers/home.py', line 55 in index
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986022 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   context, data_dict)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986024 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py', line 457 in wrapped
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986025 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   result = _action(context, data_dict, **kw)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986027 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/get.py', line 1863 in package_search
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986029 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   data_dict = item.before_search(data_dict)
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986032 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-spatial/ckanext/spatial/plugin.py', line 239 in before_search
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986034 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   from ckanext.spatial.lib import  validate_bbox
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986036 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-spatial/ckanext/spatial/lib/__init__.py', line 8 in <module>
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986038 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   from shapely.geometry import asShape
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986039 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py', line 4 in <module>
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986041 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986043 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py', line 17 in <module>
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986045 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986047 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/coords.py', line 8 in <module>
[Wed Feb 20 12:59:10.986049 2019] [:error] [pid 21182] [remote 192.168.70.1:0]   from shapely.geos import lgeos
```

I've followed the installation guide of ckan-spatial plugin but no idea what could be happening...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the apache user cannot use /tmp folder by default in some python libraries.

Executing this command line solves the problem.

> setsebool -P httpd_tmp_exec on